# How to get dependent dropdown values in form update in Laravel10

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, dropdown, edit

I'm new to Laravel. I want to show only the subcategories related to the category in select option while updating a form but here subcategory dependent dropdown displaying all its values.
Here is my code

```
//blade.php file

<div class="control-group"> <label class="control-label">Category</label> 
    <div class="controls"> 
        <select name="category" id="category" class="span8">
            @foreach($category as $row)
                <option value='{{$row->cid}}' {{(old('category', $product->category == $row->cid))?'selected':''}}>{{$row->cname}}</option>
            @endforeach
         </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group"> <label class="control-label">Sub Category</label> 
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="span8"> 
            @foreach($subcategory as $subcate) 
                <option value='{{$subcate->sid}}' {{(old('subcategory', $product->subcategory == $subcate->sid))?'selected':''}}>{{$subcate->sname}}</option>
            @endforeach</select>
    </div>
</div>

//Jquery code 

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#category").on("change", function ()
    {
        var cid = $(this).val();
        //console.log(cid);
        if (cid)
        {
        $.ajax({
        url:"getSubcategory/" + cid,
                async: false
        }).done(function (data) {
        $("select#subcategory").html(data);
        });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the jQuery part. Try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#category").on("change", function ()
    {
        var cid = $(this).val();
        //console.log(cid);
        if (cid)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "getSubcategory/" + cid,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    var subcategorySelect = $('#subcategory');
                    subcategorySelect.empty();

                    $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                        subcategorySelect.append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value", value.sid)
                            .text(value.sname));
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Using the `success` function you can clear the subcategories select box and adding the freshly retrieved ones.